# Que signifie "Rigo" ?

Tags: sens, lexique

Parlant de sa chatte, Mallarmé écrit dans une lettre du 10 mai 1897 :

> Lilith absente hier tout le jour, revient un peu et se civilise,
> malgré son Rigo.

Savez-vous ce que signifie *Rigo* ici ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Rigó Jancsi était un chanteur tzigane hongrois, devenu l'amant puis l'époux de Clara Ward, [princesse de Chimay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clara_Ward,_Princesse_de_Caraman-Chimay), événement qui a fait scandale à l'époque; cf. photo ci-dessus qui les représente.

Le nom de Rigo est utilisé métaphoriquement pour représenter le matou avec lequel cette chatte "de bonne famille" a une liaison romantique. Il a aussi donné son nom à une [pâtisserie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rig%C3%B3jancsi).

Source: [Lilith, ou la danseuse de Mallarmé réincarnée](https://www.persee.fr/doc/litt_0047-4800_2003_num_131_3_1810).